# Fill in the remaining entries that if R is ... iff inverse R is ...?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse-function

I am having a really hard time with the following table because can't there be several answers? It's not making sense to me since there can be 2 situations where it can be injective or surjective. Here is the question:

The inverse, $\displaystyle{R^{-1}}$, of a binary relation $R$, from $A$ to $B$, is the relation from $B$ to $A$ defined by $$b\hspace{3mm}R^{-1}\hspace{3mm}a\hspace{5mm}\textrm{iff}\hspace{5mm}a\hspace{3mm}R\hspace{3mm}b.$$
    Fill in the remaining entries in this table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
R\space is& iff\space \displaystyle{R^{-1}}\space is\\ \hline
total&a\space surjection\\ \hline
a\space function&\\ \hline
a\space surjection&\\ \hline
an\space injection&\\ \hline
a\space bijection&\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}

I'm confused because according to the table on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection), a surjection can also be injective, then why isn't the answer bijective for the first one? It would still make R total.

My answers were:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
R\space is& iff\space \displaystyle{R^{-1}}\space is\\ \hline
total&a\space surjection\\ \hline
a\space function&total\\ \hline
a\space surjection&a \space bijection\\ \hline
an\space injection&a \space bijection\\ \hline
a\space bijection& a \space bijection\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}

Is this correct? I don't get it really because if R is surjective (doesn't say ONLY surjective) then $\displaystyle{R^{-1}}$ must be a bijection or surjection since at most 1 element is mapped. Someone help me understand this because I don't get it at all. Isn't it just the same on each side of the table? There are 2 cases where a function is surjective and 2 cases where a function is injective so I don't get it.

Comment: Iff means the implication goes both ways. Can you think of a total relation whose inverse is not bijective? Likewise for a surjective and injective relation.

Comment: Then can't I just write the same word on both sides of the table?

Comment: @JozemiteApps You've asserted that $R$ is an injection iff $R^{-1}$ is a bijection, and also that $R^{-1}$ is a bijection iff $R$ is a bijection; so your assertions imply that "injection" is equivalent to "bijection". That's not true: consider the function $\exp$, which is injective but not bijective as a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens a bijection is an injection and surjection, that's why I put bijection for both. The table doesn't say surjection only or injection only.

Comment: Replace "total", "a function", "a surjection", "an injection" and "a bijection" with "bigger than 3", "bigger than 4", "divisible by 7", "prime" and "equal to 7" respectively, and replace $R^{1}$ by $R$. What does the question now read? How does your answer differ? (Hint: you've just asserted that all primes are equal to $7$.)

Comment: So, I basically write the same word on both sides? My professor answered the first one that total iff a surjection, but if I replace it by what you said, you're saying "bigger than 3" iff "divisible by 7" which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting this problem right now and would like to share my solution, in-order to check (your original comments from the question are in quotes):

**Question:**

The inverse, $\displaystyle{R^{-1}}$, of a binary relation $R$, from $A$ to $B$, is the relation from $B$ to $A$ defined by $$b\hspace{3mm}R^{-1}\hspace{3mm}a\hspace{5mm}\textrm{iff}\hspace{5mm}a\hspace{3mm}R\hspace{3mm}b.$$
Fill in the remaining entries in this table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
R\space is& iff\space \displaystyle{R^{-1}}\space is\\ \hline
total&a\space surjection\\ \hline
a\space function&\\ \hline
a\space surjection&\\ \hline
an\space injection&\\ \hline
a\space bijection&\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}

> I'm confused because according to the table on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection), a
> surjection can also be injective, then why isn't the answer bijective
> for the first one? It would still make R total.

Here, I make a distinction between a binary function and a binary relation. This question is taken from [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/) text book, and there the authors are dealing with binary relation. Binary function is a special case. In internet and most other text books, the topic is a binary function.

> My answers were:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
R\space is& iff\space \displaystyle{R^{-1}}\space is\\ \hline
total&a\space surjection\\ \hline
a\space function&total\\ \hline
a\space surjection&a \space bijection\\ \hline
an\space injection&a \space bijection\\ \hline
a\space bijection& a \space bijection\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}

> Is this correct? I don't get it really because if R is surjective
> (doesn't say ONLY surjective) then $\displaystyle{R^{-1}}$ must be a
> bijection or surjection since at most 1 element is mapped. Someone
> help me understand this because I don't get it at all. Isn't it just
> the same on each side of the table? There are 2 cases where a function
> is surjective and 2 cases where a function is injective so I don't get
> it.

**Well, my answers are follows:**

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
R\space is& iff\space \displaystyle{R^{-1}}\space is\\ \hline
total&a\space surjection\\ \hline
a\space function&injection\\ \hline
a\space surjection&a \space total\\ \hline
an\space injection&a \space function\\ \hline
a\space bijection& a \space bijection\\ \hline
\hline
\end{array}

Please note that the original question came with the following hint:

*Hint: Explain what’s going on in terms of “arrows” from A to B in the diagram for R.*

Here are my reasonings:

- A binary relation R is a *function* when it has the $ [\leq 1] $ arrows **out** property. When we reverse the relationship, then this corresponds to a $ [\leq 1] $ arrow **in** property. The $=$ part of the *injection* definition should guarantee that this is true even when the R is a *total function*. On the other hand, inverse relation can't be a *surjection* because that would break the *function* part of R.
- A binary relation R is a *surjection* when it has the $ [\geq 1] $ arrows **in** property. So for ${R^{-1}}\space$, there will be $ [\geq 1] $ arrows **out**, which makes it a *total*
- A binary relation R is an *injection* when it has the $ [\leq 1] $ arrows **in** property. So for ${R^{-1}}\space$, there will be $ [\leq 1] $ arrows **out**, which makes it a *function* (actually this statement is the corollary of my first bullet point)
- A binary relation R is a *bijection* when it has both the $ [= 1] $ arrow **out** and $ [= 1] $ arrow **in** property. So ${R^{-1}}\space$ will also be a *bijection* by symmetry.